# How to toggle an animation in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I am trying to make an animation on a navigation menu where when an option is clicked the other two fade out, since .fadeToggle had problems with positioning for me I decided to just animate the opacity to 0, and then back to 1 when clicked on again. (I left the CSS out the the code posted down below) 
https://jsfiddle.net/L703yvke/

```
<div id='bckDrp'>
  <div id='nav'>
    <ul id='navLst'>
      <li class='navOp' id='hme'>Home</li>
      <li class='navOp' id='abt'>About</li>
      <li class='navOp' id='prt'>Portfolio</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
var main = function(){
  $('#hme').click(function(){
    $('#abt, #prt').animate({opacity: 0},300 );
  });
  if($('#abt, #prt').css('opacity') == 0) {
    $('#hme').click(function(){
      $('#abt, #prt').animate({opacity: 1},300 );
    }
  )};
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main` function only runs once. So you are only doing that `if-statement` once. Also you are binding `click` events, which I don't think is what you are expecting it to do. Instead you can simply use a `if-else` and have your condition inside the click event:

```
var main = function(){
  $('#hme').click(function(){
    if($('#abt, #prt').css('opacity') == 0) 
        $('#abt, #prt').animate({opacity: 1},300 );
    else
        $('#abt, #prt').animate({opacity: 0},300 );
  });
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/L703yvke/1/)

Answer (score 2):

I would heavily recommend handling the animation as a transition in CSS and simply toggling a class.

## CSS

```
#abt, #prt{
    opacity:1;
    transition: opacity 300s;
}

#abt.hide, #prt.hide{
    opacity:0;
}
```

## jQuery

```
$('#hme').on('click', function(){
    $('#abt, #prt').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code :

```
var main = function() {

    $('#hme').click(function(){

        var op = $('#abt, #prt').css('opacity');

        if (op == 1)
            $('#abt, #prt').animate({opacity: 0},{duration:300} );

        else if(op == 0)
            $('#abt, #prt').animate({opacity: 1},{duration:300} );        
    })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    main();
})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div id='bckDrp'>
  <div id='nav'>
    <ul id='navLst'>
      <li class='navOp' id='hme'>Home</li>
      <li class='navOp' id='abt'>About</li>
      <li class='navOp' id='prt'>Portfolio</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
var main = function() {
    
    $('#hme').click(function(){
        
        var op = $('#abt, #prt').css('opacity');
        
        if (op == 1)
            $('#abt, #prt').animate({opacity: 0},{duration:300} );
        
        else if(op == 0)
            $('#abt, #prt').animate({opacity: 1},{duration:300} );        
    })
}
                            
$(document).ready(function(){
    main();
})
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you had a typo.... `)};` the brackets are reversed. They should be `});`

Then you could simplify a great deal by just using the built in `toggleClass();` function and dynamically getting the clicked element rather than needed to refer to each and every `id` used. This means you can add/subtract from the `#nav` list and the function will work regardless of the element `id`s. The "fade" is all handled in the CSS and you don't need to edit the function at all.

the *only* thing you'd need to edit from here are nav items in the HTML. (if they change...)

```js
var main = function(){
  $('#nav li').on('click', function() {
      var thisNav = $(this);
       thisNav.toggleClass('active');
      $('#nav li').not(thisNav).toggleClass('fadeit');
    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
ul { list-style: none; margin: 10px; padding:0; }

li { 
      display: block; 
      padding: 5px 10px; 
      margin: 10px 0; 
      text-align: center; 
      text-transform: uppercase; 
      background: #eee; 
      border: 1px solid #ddd; 
  
      /* below handles the opacity fade */
      opacity: 1; 
      transition: all 1s; }


.active, li:hover { background: #fee; }

/* below handles the opacity fade */
.fadeit { opacity: 0; transition: all 1s; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='bckDrp'>
  <div id='nav'>
    <ul id='navLst'>
      <li class='navOp' id='hme'>Home</li>
      <li class='navOp' id='abt'>About</li>
      <li class='navOp' id='prt'>Portfolio</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set your code with the sentence if, inside the callback .click;
This is necessary because the JS code is loaded only once and in this moment your sentence (if) is read only with the event .loaded()

This is a solution for you:

```
var main = function(){
    $('#hme').click(function(){
        $('#abt, #prt').animate({opacity: 0},300 );
        if($('#abt, #prt').css('opacity') == 0) {
            $('#abt, #prt').animate({opacity: 1},300 );
        }else{
            $('#abt, #prt').animate({opacity: 0},300 );
        };
    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```